# pasting many files to a single large file

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, sh, paste

i have many text files in a directory like `1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt .......2000.txt` and i want to paste them to make a large file.

In this regard i did something like

```
paste *.txt > largefile.txt
```

but the above command reads the .txt file randomly, so i need to read the files sequentially and paste as `1.txt 2.txt 3.txt....2000.txt`
please suggest a better solution for pasting many files.
Thanks and looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: `but the above command reads the .txt file randomly,` are you sure? Files should be sorted, which means `1.txt 10.txt 11.txt .... 100.txt 101.txt ... 1000.txt 1001.txt ... 2.txt ... `etc. But it should no be rnadom.

Comment: yes sir, i am sure

Comment: then can you post the output of `ech paste *.txt`? Are you sure you are using bash? What is the output of `declare -p BASH_VERSION`?

Answer (score 1):

Sort the file names numerically yourself then.

```
printf "%s\n" *.txt | sort -n | xargs -d '\n' paste
```

When dealing with many files, you may hit `ulimit -n`. On my system `ulimit -n` is `1024`, but this is a soft limit and can be raised with just like `ulimit -n 99999`.

Without raising the soft limit, go with a temporary file that would accumulate results each "round" of `ulimit -n` count of files, like:

```
touch accumulator.txt
... | xargs -d '\n' -n $(($(ulimit -n) - 1)) sh -c '
       paste accumulator.txt "$@" > accumulator.txt.sav;
       mv accumulator.txt.sav accumulator.txt
' _
cat accumulator.txt
```

Comment: it gets failure when more than 1000 files present.  it shows error like                           paste: 1022.txt: Too many open files

Comment: please suggest a better solution

Comment: `paste: 1022.txt: Too many open files ` Ugh, the `ulimit -n` must be low. Well, the only way it to merge 1024 files at a time and then marge 1024 files together... :/ But most probably you can raise `ulimit -n` yourself, it's a soft limit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead use the wildcard `*` to enumerate all your files in a directory, if your file names pattern are sequentially ordered, you can manually list all files in order and concatenate to a large file. The output order of `*` enumeration might look different in different environment, as it not works as you expect.

Below is a simple example

```
$ for i in `seq 20`;do echo $i > $i.txt;done
# create 20 test files, 1.txt, 2.txt, ..., 20.txt with number 1 to 20 in each file respectively
$ cat {1..20}.txt
# show content of all file in order 1.txt, 2.txt, ..., 20.txt
$ cat {1..20}.txt > 1_20.txt
# concatenate them to a large file named 1_20.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash or any other shell, glob expansions are done in lexicographical order. When having files numberd, this sadly means that `11.txt < 1.txt < 2.txt`. This weird ordering comes from the fact that, lexicographically, `1 < .` (<dot>-character (".")).

So here are a couple of ways to operate on your files in order:

**rename all your files:**

```
for i in *.txt; do mv "$i" "$(sprintf "%0.5d.txt" ${i%.*}"); done
paste *.txt
```

**use brace-expansion:**

Brace expansion is a mechanism that allows for the generation of arbitrary strings. For integers you can use `{n..m}` to generate all numbers from `n` to `m` or `{n..m..s}` to generate all numbers from `n` to `m` in steps of `s`:

```
paste {1..2000}.txt
```

The downside here is that it is possible that a file is missing (eg. `1234.txt`). So you can do

```
shopt -s extglob; paste ?({1..2000}.txt)
```

The pattern `?(pattern)` matches zero or one glob-matches. So this will exclude the missing files but keeps the order.